# How to load different assets based on my layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have 3 layouts in /views/layouts for 3 distinct sections of my website.

My assets looks like:

```
/javascripts/layout1/*.js
/javascripts/layout2/*.js
/javascripts/layout3/*.js

/stylesheets/layout1/*.css
/stylesheets/layout2/*.css
/stylesheets/layout3/*.css
```

Now in a specific layout, say layout1, how can I only include the styles/javascript files for this layout?

Comment: As far as I know you can't achieve that with the asset pipeline. You need to look into other solutions like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 6):

You can achive this by following the five steps

> Note: I am assuming layout1  layout2 and layout3 are manifest files
>   like application.js and application.css

1) Create a manifest file for new layout

> create the following js files on assets/javascripts/

layout1.js

```
//= require_tree ./layout1
```

layout2.js

```
//= require_tree ./layout2
```

layout3.js

```
//= require_tree ./layout3
```

> create the following css files on assets/stylesheets

layout1.css

```
/*  
*= require_tree ./layout1
*/
```

layout2.css

```
/*
*= require_tree ./layout1
*/
```

layout3.css

```
/*
 *= require_tree ./layout1
 */
```

2) Add this line to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( layout1.js layout1.css layout2.js layout2.css layout3.js layout3.css )`

3) Include the following line to respective layouts

layout1.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'layout1', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'layout1', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

layout2.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'layout2', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'layout2', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

layout3.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'layout3', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'layout3', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

4) Include layout in your controller

layout_one_controller.rb

```
class LayoutOneController < ApplicationController
    layout 'layout1'
    def index
    end
end
```

layout_two_controller.rb

```
class LayoutTwoController < ApplicationController
    layout 'layout2'
    def indiex
    end
end
```

layout_three_controller.rb

```
class LayoutThreeController < ApplicationController
    layout 'layout3'
    def index
    end
end
```

5) Restart your application

Comment: Tell me if you face any difficulties implementing this

Comment: Just to clarify, my layout folders in assets will have many files. I updated my question to show that.

Comment: @Blankman, answer updated, you just have to create the manifest files as explained in the point 1 in this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `layout1` assets in your app, just call it in your layout:

```
#app/views/layout/layout_1.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    :layout_1, media: 'all',  %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :layout_1 %>
```

--

As mentioned by `@Ramesh Kumar Thiyagarajan`, you'll have to include any extra asset files (over and above `application.css/.js`) in your `assets.rb` initializer:

```
#config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( layout_1.js layout_1.css )
```

--

You'll also have to define when each `layout` is called:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout :set_layout

   private

   def set_layout
      # conditional for determining layout
   end
end
```